# Nested queries. Select as column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to write this query in ROR?

```
SELECT column_1, 
(SELECT name FROM table_2 WHERE table_2.column_1 = table_1.column_1) as name 
FROM table_1;
```

Comment: A literal answer would be "yes".  Try asking how and/or showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible:

```
Table_1.select("column_1, (SELECT name FROM table_2 WHERE table_2.column_1 = table_1.column_1) as name")
```

If you will user Arel it will seems yet more complicated then this.

But exists other ways to simplify this query:

- split it to two query and merge it together in Rails
- using `joins` method for join table_1 and table_2 and select field `table_2.name`.

Comment: I tried like you, but i have other problem in this case.
I want to do something like this:
User.select('id, (SELECT name FROM categories WHERE sex = users.sex AND ? BETWEEN old_from AND old_to LIMIT 1)', 21) but it doesn't work